# Как запретить пользователю доступ к php,json файлам через .htaccess, чтобы работали ajax запросы?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess

Я гуглил, но каждый ответ кардинально отличается от предыдущего, поэтому никак не могу разобраться с этим.

Есть некоторые php и json файлы, которые должны быть не доступными для пользователя (переход по прямой ссылке, например, http::/site.ru/file.php ) , но в то же время они должны принимать ajax запросы от скрипта js (в частности $.post ).

Пробовал создавать отдельную папку для "недопустимых" файлов и кидать туда .htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch ~ "\.(php|htm|html|json)$">
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Но при обращении ajax запроса к необходимым файлам вылетала 500 ошибка.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно это реализовать именно через .htaccess?

Comment: ммм, М.Б. запретить GET?

Comment: Объясните подробнее, пожалуйста, не совсем понимаю

Comment: https://serverfault.com/a/270971/577684 - попробуй это

Comment: пример GET запроса - https://www.google.com/?q=http%20get%20post%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0 в случае же с POST значение переменной `q` будет не видно

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch `method: 'POST',`

Comment: Если json секретные, то зачем их хранить в публичной папке. Если php, доступный на пост, то надежней проверять на пост в начале самого php.

Comment: А как хранить файлы не в публичной папке?

Comment: возможно автор уже нашел ответ, но немного поясню, суммируя и расширяя имеющиеся сообщения. можно сделать еще один каталог, вложенный по отношению к корневому, положить в него секретные файлы и закрыть его htaccess, раз он тут применяется. все обращение к ним делать из php скриптов. чтобы подробнее написать надо знать на чистом php написано или использован фреймфорк и какой. по доступности по прямой ссылке, смотря что Вы имеете под этим понятием. если файл выполняется, то код не показывается, а результат его выполнения. в самих php файлах и можно все предусмотреть, включая проверки на метод.